# jquery AJAX sent data in key value pair

Tags: c#, jquery

In my aspx page, i have the js like this :-

```
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $("#btnLoad").click(function () {

        var dataForAjax = "{'datakey':'hello'}"

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Ajax__Demo.aspx/SendFile",
            data: dataForAjax,                
            success: function (msg) {
                alert(msg); // Problem with this line. It is not showing the value.
            }
        });

    });
</script>
```

In the same webpage code behind class file ,i have the webmethod defined like this:-

```
[WebMethod]        
    public static string SendFile(string key, string data)
    {
        return data;
    }
```

For some reason, i am able to get the data in the alert used on the html side. alert(msg); is giving me nothing and i am expecting to get the passed value back. In this case it should be 'Hello'.

I am missing something very small here, please help me out here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alter these.

The AJAX Call

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnLoad").click(function (evt) {
        var dataForAjax = "{'datakey':'hello'}";
        $.ajax({
            contentType: "application/json",
            data: dataForAjax,
            type: "POST",
            url: 'Test1.aspx/SendFile',
            success: function (msg) {
                var msg = msg.hasOwnProperty("d") ? msg.d : msg;
                alert(msg.datakey);
            }
        });
        evt.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

The `WebMethod`

```
[WebMethod]
public static object SendFile(string datakey)
{
    return new
    {
        datakey = datakey
    };
}
```

Hope this helps.

Update:

1. `` `evt.preventDefault `` is for preventing postback in case your control was something like `input type="submit"` or `asp:Button`
2. `.d` is ASP.NET 3.5+ feature to prevent XSS vulnerability. ( [link here](http://encosia.com/never-worry-about-asp-net-ajaxs-d-again/) )
3. The return type is object for the web method for automatic serialization ( [link here](http://encosia.com/asp-net-web-services-mistake-manual-json-serialization/) )
4. Also you could omit`dataType` in `$.ajax` call but `contentType` is an absolute necessity ( [link here](http://encosia.com/save-yourself-some-typing-when-you-call-asp-net-services/) )

Comment: Thanks this works. But why it is so complicated. I was thinking it will implicitly prepare the return msg object. And what is the use of preventDefault().

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
var dataForAjax = "{'datakey':'hello'}"
```

Should be:

```
var dataForAjax = {'datakey':'hello'}
```

AJAX does not (by default anyway) send json - it sends `FORM` `INPUT` elements! jQuery is nice and will convert javascript objects into that for you.

If you really need to you can send json, but I really doubt you do, it's rare to do that.

Comment: i tried with the new syntax, but it is still not working.. Something else is missing...

Comment: Your webmethod doesn't look right to me. You are saying 'datakey', but the webmethod doesn't have that anywhere. Try @Rattlemouse's change.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar enough with c#. You may want to install firebug and watch to see if the ajax request really does go through (you can click on it and see what is being sent, and what returns.) Try putting some random text in your webmethod - just to see if anything at all comes back.

Answer (score 0):

When you send data to method you must send apropriate key-value pairs, using object in Javascript.
Examle for you method:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$("#btnLoad").click(function () {

    var dataForAjax = {'key' :'datakey', 'data' : 'hello'};

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Ajax__Demo.aspx/SendFile",
        data: dataForAjax,                
        success: function (msg) {
            alert(msg); // Problem with this line. It is not showing the value.
        }
    });

});
```